# Android CheckBoxes

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I am making a contacts manager application and have a list of contacts populated with checkboxes beside each one (using ListView). When running the application I am able to check and deselect each one. I want to delete the contacts that have been checked (when pressing the delete button) but I am unsure how to do this. Each contact is associated with its own unique ID and my plan was, once the user selects the delete button, store all the contactsId's which have been checked in an ArrayList then iterate through the list and delete those contacts from my database. However, I am unsure on how to implement this.

```
Here is my code for Delete Contacts:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DeleteContacts extends ListActivity {

    // Initializing the listView and the contactList. The contactList is made public so that it is
    // accessible from any class.

    private ListView lv;
    private TextView contactId;
    private String sortOrder;
    ListAdapter adapter;

    public static final String LAST = "lastName";
    public static final String FIRST = "firstName";
    public static final String MOBILE = "mobileNumber";

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfContacts;


    //The object that allows me to manipulate the Database
    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getData(FIRST);



        // Checking to make sure that there are contacts to display.
        // Then setting up the view of the Home Screen
        if(listOfContacts.size()!=0){
            setupListView(listOfContacts);
        }

    }

    private void getData(String order) {
        listOfContacts = dbTools.getAllContacts(order);
    }

    private void setupListView(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfContacts){

        lv = getListView();

//      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
//
//          // Once any contact is clicked, the details are passed as extra information for
//          // the ViewContactsDetails class (using a Bundle). The application is then taken to
//          // the ViewContactDetails screen.
//          @Override
//          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View clickedView, int clickedViewPosition, long id){
//
//              //When an item is clicked get the TextView with matching checkId
//
//              contactId = (TextView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.contactId);
//
//              //Convert that contactId into a String
//
//              String contactIdValue = contactId.getText().toString();
//
//              // Intention to go to the ViewContactDetails class/screen
//
//              Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), ViewContactDetails.class);
//              // Put additional data in for EditContact to use
//
//              theIntent.putExtra("contactId", contactIdValue);
//
//              // calls for ViewContactDetails
//
//              startActivity(theIntent);
//
//          }
//
//      });

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DeleteContacts.this, listOfContacts, R.layout.activity_delete_contacts, new String[] {"contactId", "lastName", "firstName"}, new int[] {R.id.contactId, R.id.lastName, R.id.firstName});

        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        // Once the add contact button is pressed, the application is taken to the AddContact screen.
        case R.id.addImageButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddContact.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.deleteButton:




            break;

        case R.id.sort_lastName:
            sortOrder = LAST;
            getData(sortOrder);
            setupListView(listOfContacts);
            break;

        case R.id.sort_firstName:
            sortOrder = FIRST;
            getData(sortOrder);
            setupListView(listOfContacts);
            break;  

        case R.id.sort_mobileNumber:
            sortOrder = MOBILE;
            getData(sortOrder);
            setupListView(listOfContacts);
            break;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }

}

Here is my XML File for each entry:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contactImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/contactsmall" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/

Comment: Did you  get any solution from above link??

Comment: That tutorial refers to just one particular checkbox being checked and performing a task. However, in my case I have a ListView so it requires you to find out all the contacts in the ListView that have been checked and find their respective Id's

Comment: So didnt get a solution from that link

Comment: I am trying to implement an onClick method on my checkBox as follows: public void onCheckBoxChecked(View view){
  ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
  contactId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactId);
  String contactIdValue = contactId.getText().toString();
  ids.add(contactIdValue);
  
 }

Comment: And then once the delete button is pressed, iterate through the ids and delete contacts respectively. However, whenever I click on the checkbox, the application crashes

Comment: is the issue that it cannot track what the contactId is when I check?

Answer (score 0):

For handling views on list view cell you have to code in getView() of list adapter.  Following is my code snippet. SugarBean is my array that has information for listview cells.

```
public class ListAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<SugarBean> {

    protected SugarBean[] items;
    protected int listViewCellId;

    public ListAdapter(ListviewHelper helper, int listViewCellId, SugarBean[] items) {
        super(helper.getActivity(), listViewCellId, items);

        this.items = items;
        this.listViewCellId= listViewCellId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final SugarBean beanObject = items[position];// list view cell 

        View v = convertView;

        //load the custom cell
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)              helper.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(listViewCellId, null);
        } 

                RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tableRow);
                // handle all views here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is  when use clicks on checkbox, add id in an array (this would take place under onItemClickListener). when you press delete button check the id. If the same id exists in array then delete it otherwise leave it. And after that a new array of items pass to adapter or notifyData to regenerate the listview.

Comment: I think I am having trouble accessing the contactId, converting to a string and passing it to the array

Comment: you can store contact id as an int also.